# How to get greyout past dates and time on time and date picker in android studio java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, datepicker

I am having problem with my code and please help me to grey out the past date and time picker in this code,  please help me out,

```
    private void showDateTimeDialog(final Button btnStart) {
    final Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();



    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dateSetListener=new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {


        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,month);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,dayOfMonth);
            
            TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timeSetListener=new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hourOfDay);
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);


                    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd HH:mm");

                    btnStart.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()));

                }
            };


            new TimePickerDialog(getContext(),timeSetListener,calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),false).show();
        }

    };


    new DatePickerDialog(getContext(),dateSetListener,calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
}
```

My date and time picker would pop up after they click the button and the button text change to date

Comment: Can you restate the question, what are you trying to grey out and when exactlly?

Comment: grey out past dates on the date picker